# Installed app doesn't open intent

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have an instant app with two features with differents urls.
Launching the example.com/A from the android studio this code works nice, the activity B (or feature B) is opened.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://example.com/id/"+mIds.get(mPager.getCurrentItem())));
        intent.setPackage(getPackageName());
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        startActivity(intent);
```

But running the installed app, when I press the same button I get the error:

```
     android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent 
{ act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] 
dat=https://example.com/... pkg=com.example.myapp }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the other way around? Can you take a look at the merged manifest for the installed app module and check if the activities are there with the right intent-filter? Also, you shouldn't setPackage on your intents for the instant app, since if the feature module isn't there, you will get the exception you mentioned (hence my first question).

Comment: An example on how to use the intent: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/blob/master/hello-feature-module/features/hello/src/main/java/com/instantappsamples/feature/hello/HelloActivity.java And like Hassan said, double check your installed-app's merged manifest, is your feature B there?